# creating new elements with html5 data attributes defined in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a new element with html5 data attributes defined, however they are not showing in the DOM (unlike when using say .addClass). is this intended behavior?

this creates an element *without* the `data-foo` attributs:

```
-> $("<div>foo</div>").data('foo', 'bar').addClass('class')
=> <div class="class">foo</div>
```

i had to declare it in the constructor

```
-> $("<div data-foo='bar'>foo</div>").addClass('class')
=> <div class="class" data-foo="bar">foo</div>
```

shouldn't the .data method work do the same?

Comment: iirc, `.data` does not set or modify data attributes, it just reads them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:

- http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/09/using-jquerys-data-apis

> `4`. No jQuery data API ever changes HTML5 data-* attributes.
>
> Most uses of .data() and .removeData() are still for the original
>   purpose of associating data with DOM elements in memory. Updating DOM
>   attributes each time data was changed would slow things down for no
>   good reason. Also, it's not even possible to serialize all data types
>   that might be attached to a DOM element, such as functions, references
>   to other DOM elements, or custom JavaScript objects.
>
> Rule: To update or remove HTML5 data-* attributes, use jQuery's
>   .attr() or .removeAttr() methods.

So, use the usual `attr`...

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't just a jQuery thing, either. If you do `element.data = [something]` it will associate that data in memory, but not reflect it in the DOM as an inline attribute. You'd have to use `element.setAttribute()` [instead of jQ's .attr()].